# Why am I getting a type error : "function_name" is not a function at

Tags: javascript

myjs.js:61 Uncaught TypeError: datRed.newPos is not a function
    at updateGameArea (myjs.js:61)

Why am I getting an error? It's stopping me from making an HTML game. The line `datRed.newPos();` seems to cause this and if I comment it out, the game will have no errors but the component datRed won't be able to move

I've tried debugging. I can't think of anything else. Checked the code for spelling mistakes. Nothing

Here's my js file

```
var datRed;
var daBlueCheese;


function startGame() {
    // component creations
    datRed = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 250 - 15);
    daBlueCheese = new component(120, 40, "blue", 10, 375 - 15);
    myGameArea.start();

}
// the game area
var myGameArea = {
    canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
    start: function() {
        this.canvas.width = 680;
        this.canvas.height = 500;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    },
    clear: function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

// componenet constructor
function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}


// the function that is called to
//change the movement properties for components
function newPos() {
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY;
};





// where the game area gets updated
function updateGameArea() {


    myGameArea.clear();


    datRed.newPos();
    datRed.update();

    daBlueCheese.newPos();
    daBlueCheese.update();
}


// movement for the componenets for each direction
function moveup() {
    datRed.speedY -= 1;
    daBlueCheese.speedY -= 1;
}

function movedown() {
    datRed.speedY += 1;
    daBlueCheese.speedY += 1;
}

function moveleft() {
    datRed.speedX -= 1;
    daBlueCheese.speedX -= 1;
}

function moveright() {
    datRed.speedX += 1;
    daBlueCheese.speedX += 1;
}
```

here is my html file

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Ahmed's game</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Game, HTML game, JS game">
    <meta name="author" content="Ahmed">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale= 1.0">



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css">
    <script src="myjs.js"></script>



</head>

<body onload="startGame()">



    <button onclick="moveup()">UP</button>
    <button onclick="movedown()">DOWN</button>
    <button onclick="moveleft()">LEFT</button>
    <button onclick="moveright()">RIGHT</button>






</body>

</html>
```

here is my css file

```
canvas {
    border: 3px solid red;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

I want to be able to use the newPos function without an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring `newPos` globally but trying to access it as if it were a member of your components.

Rather than declare `newPos` globally, define it in your `component()` constructor:

```js
function component(text) {
    this.example =  text;
    
    this.newPos = function() {
      console.log("newPos called on " + this.example);
    }
};

var datRed = new component("datRed");
datRed.newPos();

var daBlueCheese = new component("daBlueCheese");
daBlueCheese.newPos();
```

I've added a few other lines just to make it a brief but verifiable demo.

Comment: wow I just did what you said and it worked perfectly. My components datRed and daBlueCheese are in my game area and are correctly moving up and down. You're smart, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`datRed` is initialized as this:

```
datRed = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 250 - 15);
```

And nowhere in `component` is `newPos` referenced, so there is no connection between `datRed` and `newPost`.

`newPost` is just a function that you would call directly, as in:

```
newPos();
```

However, if you did, it wouldn't do what you want it to, because it is likely that `this` inside the function doesn't reference what you want it to.

To correct this, you need to make `newPos` a member of `datRed` like this:

```
datRed.newPos = function(){
  this.x += this.speedX;
  this.y += this.speedY;
}
```

Then, because `datRed` is the instance returned from `new component()`, `this` would refer to that instance.

Comment: @TylerRoper I was working on an edit to explain that as you posted your comment.